# Should we use Thread.sleep( ) when doing something with timeout?

Tags: java

Consider the following two blocks:

```
    // block one
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < TIMEOUT) {
        if( SOME_CONDITION_IS_MET ) {
            // do something
            break;
        } else {
            Thread.sleep( 100 );
        }
    }

    // block two
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < TIMEOUT) {
        if( SOME_CONDITION_IS_MET ) {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
```

The difference between the two is that the first one has a Thread.sleep(), which seemingly can reduce condition checking in `while` and `if`. However, is there any meaningful benefit by having this sleep, assuming the `if` condition doesn't have a heavy computation? Which one would you recommend for implementing timeout?

Comment: Neither. Both a fairly dirty hacks, and should be avoided when possible. Having said that, the first gives the CPU a chance to do something else - the second option eats one entire core for absolutely no reason.

Comment: While the second will have the operation take at least 100 ms which can be fairly long if the condition is only becoming true 1 µs after it was checked for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key difference is that the second method involves [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). If `SOME_CONDITION_IS_MET` doesn't involve any I/O, the second approach will likely consume an entire CPU core. This is a wasteful thing to do (but could be perfectly reasonable in some -- pretty rare -- circumstances). On the flip side, the second approach has lower latency.

I agree with Boris that, in a general setting, both approaches are basically hacks. A better way would be to use proper [synchronization primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to signal the condition.

Comment: _@NPE: Thanks for the answer. I tried out the Condition interface. However, somehow I can't make the signalAll() working. I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205627/condition-instance-signalall-doesnt-return